# Biblatex pageref customization

Tags: biblatex, back-referencing, pageref

I would like to customize the way back references are printed.

I would like the list of pages where references are cited to be printed on a new line, just below a bibliographic entry and its eventual abstract.

I would also like to change the way `backrefstyle=all+` works. I would like to add an `and` before the last entry in the `pageref` list, in case the `pageref` list has more than two entries.

I have browsed through the Biblatex documentation but I haven't found the way to change the behavior of `backrefstyle=all+`. Could you help me?

Here’s what I currently have:

The problem is that the `pageref`-list appears twice and the `backrefpage` or `backrefpages` fields do not appear in front of the list ; as well as a comma problem that appears at the beginning of the list if this one displays only one item. (`\nopunct` didn't fix the problem.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=verbose-trad1,
backref=true,
backrefstyle=all+,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{abstract}{\par\vspace{\baselineskip} Abstract : #1}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
    \printfield{abstract}\par%
    \vspace{\baselineskip}%
    \nopunct\printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}%
    \finentry%
}

\begin{document}

Bla\footcite{kastenholz}
\clearpage
Bla\footcite{kastenholz}
\clearpage
Bla\footcite{kastenholz}
\clearpage
Bla bla bla
\clearpage
Bla\footcite{kastenholz}
\clearpage
Bla bla bla
\clearpage
Bla\footcite{kastenholz}
\clearpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here's the result I'd like to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For printing the back-references you will want to keep in mind that one should almost never print punctuation or space directly outside of `\setunit` in a `biblatex` context. Furthermore, the field formats should not contain leading or trailing space of punctuation. Using `\setunit` properly should get rid of all problems with undesirable punctuation. You can make sure the back-references are printed only once by redefining the macro that would usually print them (before `finentry`) to do nothing.

The actual formatting of the back-references is much trickier since placing the 'and' requires looping through the list once before printing to count the printed 'chunks'. The code shown below is adapted from the original definitions. But where the original definitions print their output directly, we store a 'chunk' in a helper macro and increase a counter. Then at the end we loop through the chunks and print them.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=verbose-trad1,
backref=true,
backrefstyle=all+,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{}

\newbibmacro*{bastien:pageref}{%
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {}
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
       {\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace}
       {\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}%
     \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{abstract}{\bibstring{abstract}\addcolon\addnbspace#1}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \setunit{\par\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}}%
  \printfield{abstract}%
  \setunit{\par\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}}%
  \usebibmacro{bastien:pageref}%
  \finentry
}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{pageref:total}
\newcounter{pageref:loop}
\DeclareListWrapperFormat{pageref}{%
  \setcounter{pageref:total}{0}%
  #1%
  \setcounter{pageref:loop}{0}%
  \loop
    \addtocounter{pageref:loop}\@ne
    \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref:loop}}{1}
      {\ifnumequal{\value{pageref:loop}}{\value{pageref:total}}
         {\setcounter{liststop}{\value{pageref:total}}%
          \printdelim{finallistdelim}}
         {\printdelim{multilistdelim}}}
      {}%
    \csuse{pagerefc@chung@\the\value{pageref:loop}}%
  \ifnum \value{pageref:loop}<\value{pageref:total}
  \repeat
}

\renewbibmacro*{pageref:comp}[1]{%
  \numdef\abx@range@prev{\abx@range@prev+1}%
  \ifinteger{#1}
    {\def\abx@range@num{#1}%
     \def\abx@range@this{1}%
     \ifnumequal{\abx@range@this}{\abx@range@last}
       {}
       {\def\abx@range@prev{-1}}}
    {\ifrmnum{#1}
       {\numdef\abx@range@num{\rmntonum{#1}}%
        \def\abx@range@this{2}%
        \ifnumequal{\abx@range@this}{\abx@range@last}
          {}
          {\def\abx@range@prev{-1}}}
       {\undef\abx@range@num
        \def\abx@range@this{0}%
        \def\abx@range@prev{-1}}}%
  \ifdef\abx@range@num
    {\ifnumequal{\abx@range@num}{\abx@range@prev}
       {\def\abx@range@hold{#1}%
        \numdef\abx@range@diff{\abx@range@diff+1}}
       {\usebibmacro{pageref:dump}%
        \addtocounter{pageref:total}\@ne
        \csgdef{pagerefc@chung@\the\value{pageref:total}}{%
          \ifhyperref
            {\hyperlink{page.#1}{#1}}
            {#1}}}%
     \edef\abx@range@prev{\abx@range@num}}
    {\usebibmacro{pageref:dump}%
     \addtocounter{pageref:total}\@ne
     \csgdef{pagerefc@chung@\the\value{pageref:total}}{%
       \ifhyperref
         {\hyperlink{page.#1}{#1}}
         {#1}}%
     \def\abx@range@prev{-1}}%
  \edef\abx@range@last{\abx@range@this}}

\renewbibmacro*{pageref:dump}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\abx@range@diff}{0}
    {\ifcase\abx@pagerefstyle\relax % two
       \csxappto{pagerefc@chung@\the\value{pageref:total}}{%
         \noexpand\bibrangedash
         \noexpand\ifhyperref
           {\noexpand\hyperlink{page.\expandonce\abx@range@hold}{\expandonce\abx@range@hold}}
           {\expandonce\abx@range@hold}}%
     \or % three
       \addtocounter{pageref:total}\@ne
       \csxdef{pagerefc@chung@\the\value{pageref:total}}{%
         \noexpand\ifhyperref
           {\noexpand\hyperlink{page.\expandonce\abx@range@hold}{\expandonce\abx@range@hold}}
           {\expandonce\abx@range@hold}}%
     \or % two+
       \ifnumless{\abx@range@diff}{2}
         {\csxappto{pagerefc@chung@\the\value{pageref:total}}{%
            \noexpand\sqspace
             \noexpand\ifhyperref
               {\noexpand\hyperlink{page.\expandonce\abx@range@hold}{\noexpand\bibstring{sequens}}}
               {\noexpand\bibstring{sequens}}}}
         {\csxappto{pagerefc@chung@\the\value{pageref:total}}{%
            \noexpand\bibrangedash
            \noexpand\ifhyperref
               {\hyperlink{page.\expandonce\abx@range@hold}{\noexpand\abx@range@hold}}
               {\expandonce\abx@range@hold}}}%
     \or % three+
       \ifnumless{\abx@range@diff}{2}
         {\csxappto{pagerefc@chung@\the\value{pageref:total}}{%
            \noexpand\sqspace
             \noexpand\ifhyperref
               {\noexpand\hyperlink{page.\expandonce\abx@range@hold}{\noexpand\bibstring{sequens}}}
               {\noexpand\bibstring{sequens}}}}
         {\ifnumless{\abx@range@diff}{3}
            {\csxappto{pagerefc@chung@\the\value{pageref:total}}{%
               \noexpand\sqspace
               \noexpand\ifhyperref
                 {\noexpand\hyperlink{page.\expandonce\abx@range@hold}{\noexpand\bibstring{sequentes}}}
                 {\noexpand\bibstring{sequentes}}}}
            {\csxappto{pagerefc@chung@\the\value{pageref:total}}{%
                \noexpand\bibrangedash
                \noexpand\ifhyperref
                  {\noexpand\hyperlink{page.\expandonce\abx@range@hold}{\expandonce\abx@range@hold}}
                  {\expandonce\abx@range@hold}}}}%
     \else % all+
       \ifnumless{\abx@range@diff}{2}
         {\csxappto{pagerefc@chung@\the\value{pageref:total}}{%
            \noexpand\sqspace
            \noexpand\ifhyperref
              {\noexpand\hyperlink{page.\expandonce\abx@range@hold}{\noexpand\bibstring{sequens}}}
              {\noexpand\bibstring{sequens}}}}
         {\csxappto{pagerefc@chung@\the\value{pageref:total}}{%
            \noexpand\sqspace
            \noexpand\ifhyperref
              {\noexpand\hyperlink{page.\expandonce\abx@range@hold}{\noexpand\bibstring{sequentes}}}
              {\noexpand\bibstring{sequentes}}}}%
     \fi
     \def\abx@range@diff{0}}
    {}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}

Bla\footcite{kastenholz}
Bla\footcite{sigfridsson}
Bla\footcite{worman}
Bla\footcite{geer}
\clearpage
Bla\footcite{kastenholz}
Bla\footcite{sigfridsson}
Bla\footcite{worman}
\clearpage
Bla\footcite{kastenholz}
Bla\footcite{sigfridsson}
Bla\footcite{worman}
\clearpage
Bla bla bla
Bla\footcite{sigfridsson}
\clearpage
Bla\footcite{kastenholz}
Bla\footcite{sigfridsson}
Bla\footcite{geer}
\clearpage
Bla bla bla
Bla\footcite{geer}
\clearpage
Bla\footcite{kastenholz}
Bla\footcite{sigfridsson}
Bla\footcite{geer}
\clearpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Cit. on pp. 1 sqq., 5, and 7.]